# Removing from Doubly LinkedList in O(1)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I know that's the time complexity to remove an element from doubly linkedlist is O(1) and it seems obvious and clear BUT what happens if we don't receive an element to remove it but the one which is wrapped by the element?

for example if we define a class Element to wrap a String (To provide pointer pointing to the next and previous element) , we can do the removal in O(1) if the method receives that element as input not the string !

if the remove method receives the string , it has to search through the list to find the corresponding element , right ? so the time complexity in this case would be O(n) , not O(1) anymore

```
  class Element{
    String content;
    Element next;
    Element previous;
  }

  class LinkedList{
    ...
    public remove(String s){
        //it has to first find the element corresponding to this String !
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? It would seem as though you provided all the answers...

Comment: I thought that I am wrong with something ! so in real implementation it's not O(1) as it's always said

Comment: Sure it is. But exact words matter. Removal (of a node) is constant. *Search* is, of course, linear time. That's why intrusive linked lists (where the item and the list node are unified) are as useful as they are.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh - Removing a Node from a Doubly Linked List is always O(1) as long as you have the Node to remove. In your case, your algorithm first needs to find the node. Finding the matching node is O(n). Removing the Node is still O(1).

Comment: Perhaps not the proper approach, but I find this works out better if you use a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: If we use HashMap and Doubly LinkedList together then it would be easy to find and delete node with O(1)

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right.

Remove is considered `O(1)` (when you do `remove(Element)`), but usually this goes together with a find operation (i.e. `remove(String)` or `remove(find(String))`), which is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

This linked list ([Circular, doubly linked list, how to manage the node to object relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108378/circular-doubly-linked-list-how-to-manage-the-node-to-object-relationship?noredirect=1#comment33573906_22108378)) uses a very suspect method which inserts properties into the objects being added to the list. It makes removal O(1) without searching for the object, but at the risk of property name clashes and a performance penalty if you're adding primitive types to the list (they get boxed when the properties are added).