# Circular, doubly linked list, how to manage the node to object relationship?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This LinkedList function uses a very dodgy method to avoid client code needing to know about the linking nodes. Each list creates a unique string which is used to intrusively insert properties into the objects being added to the list. Does anyone know of a better way to do this? I should mention that removing objects in constant time is a requirement.

It does mean that client code looks like:

```
var myList = new LinkedList()

var a = new Something()
var b = new SomethingElse()

myList.addTail(a)
myList.addTail(b)

myList.remove(a)
myList.remove(b)
```

which is nice and readable, but the insertion of properties into the objects (which might clash with existing properties) is shaky, to say the least (although it can be documented and the property name prefix could be passed in to the LinkedList constructor).

This is the LinkedList code:

```
var LinkedList = (function() {

    var id = 0

    var Node = function(obj, p, n) {
        this.item = obj
        this.prev = p
        this.next = n
    }

    var list = function() {
        this.length = 0
        this.nodeName = '_' + id++ + 'lnn'
        this.root = new Node(null)
        this.root.next = this.root
        this.root.prev = this.root
    }

    list.prototype = {

        insertBefore : function(obj, item) {
            var node = new Node(item, obj.prev, obj)
            obj.prev.next = node
            obj.prev = node
            item[this.nodeName] = node
            ++this.length
        },

        insertAfter : function(obj, item) {
            var node = new Node(item, obj, obj.next)
            obj.next.prev = node
            obj.next = node
            item[this.nodeName] = node
            ++this.length
        },

        addTail : function(item) {
            this.insertBefore(this.root, item)
        },

        addHead : function(item) {
            this.insertAfter(this.root, item)
        },

        remove : function(item) {
            var node = item[this.nodeName]
            node.prev.next = node.next
            node.next.prev = node.prev
            delete node.item[this.nodeName]
            --this.length
        },

        popHead : function() {
            if(this.length > 0) {
                var node = this.root.next
                node.prev.next = node.next
                node.next.prev = node.prev
                delete node.item[this.nodeName]
                --this.length
                return node.item
            }
            return null
        },

        popTail : function() {
            if(this.length > 0) {
                var node = this.root.prev
                node.prev.next = node.next
                node.next.prev = node.prev
                delete node.item[this.nodeName]
                --this.length
                return node.item
            }
            return null
        },

        forEach : function(callback, context) {
            var node = this.root.next
            var index = 0
            while(node !== this.root) {
                var next = node.next
                if(callback.call(context, node.item, index) === false) {
                    return false
                }
                node = next
                ++index
            }
            return true
        },

        removeIf : function(callback, context) {
            var node = this.root.next
            while(node !== this.root) {
                var next = node.next
                if(callback.call(context, node.item) === true) {
                    node.prev.next = next
                    node.next.prev = node.prev
                    delete node.item[this.nodeName]
                    --this.length
                }
                node = next
            }
        },

        toString : function() {
            var s = this.length.toString()
            var sep = ':<'
            this.forEach(function(i, index) {
                s += sep + i.toString()
                sep = ','
            })
            return s + '>'
        }
    }

    return list
})()
```

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Not quite - I need constant time removal of arbitrary elements which I don't think your one will give me.

Comment: That's not how a normal linked list works. Should have included in question

Comment: Ah, good point, edited for clarity

Comment: Still not clear in the question description what exactly the specific problem is, nor in example code. Circular/doubly linked lists still do not usually have constant time removal or arbitrary elements - only the element you have an iterator on... Please don't change questions after people type out working code examples to your original question.

Comment: Removing from a doubly linked list is O(1) (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497978/removing-from-doubly-linkedlist-in-o1), the problem is how to manage the insertion of nodes into the objects in a safe way (I suspect it's not possible but wondered if anyone has come up with anything useful)

Comment: It's constant time removal not from an arbitrary element, but one you already have reference to with an iterator. It is constant time removal of a given element, if you have the element already found. What do you mean 'safe'? Insertion where? Of a node into the list?

Comment: This implementation is intrusive, it adds a node property to any object being added to the list which is then used when removal is requested (hence O(1)). The name of the property might clash with an existing property in the object (or get overwritten accidentally) which is the problem I'm trying to solve (not by coming up with a name which won't ever clash, which is impossible.)

Comment: Again, I already spent a bunch of time answering the original question. My implementation of nodes and iterators easily extends to circular, see the Node function in mine.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question wasn't really clear. I need a way to associate an object with the node in the list so that I can get to the node via the object in constant time.

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer so no, sorry, I can't accept it. I don't think the question is that badly worded, I'll just leave it here in case someone else comes across it and has any other ideas.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you need, given that the named function is `LinkedList`, there is no mention of it needing to be circular in the description text, and I had to ask so many questions :) open a new one and make the question clearer. A good metric of question clarity is if we can read only the sentence with a question mark and know what you need.

Comment: I need to know how to manage the node to object relationship...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
function LinkedList(initialValues){
  var head = null,
    version = 0,
    list = {
      push: function(){
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0),
          pushable = null;
        while(args.length && (pushable = args.shift()))
          head = new Node(pushable).append(head);
        version++;
        return this;
      },
      pop: function(){
        var popped = head;
        head = head.next();
        version++;
        return popped.value();
      },
      peek: function(){
        return head && head.value();
      },
      iterator: function(){
        return new Iterator(head, version);
      },
      toString: function(){
        var vals = [],
          iter = new Iterator(head, version);
        while(iter.node()){
          vals.push(iter.node().toString());
          iter.step();
        }
        return ["("].concat(vals).concat(")").join(" ");
      },
      size: function(){
        var iter = new Iterator(head, version);
        while(iter.node()){
          iter.step();
        }
        return iter.index();
      }
    };
  return list.push.apply(list, initialValues);

  function Node(input){
    var content = input,
      next = null;
    return {
      next: function(){
        return next;
      },
      value: function(){
        return content;
      },
      append: function(node){
        next = node;
        return this;
      },
      set: function(val){
        return content = val;
      },
      toString: function(){
        return content.toString();
      }
    };
  }

  function Iterator(base, v){
    var current = base, index = 0,
      checkSafe = function(){
        if(v === version)
          return true;
        else
          throw "The iterator is no longer valid, list modified.";
      };
    return {
      node: function(){
        checkSafe();
        return current;
      },
      step: function(){
        checkSafe();
        current = current.next();
        index++;
        return this;
      },
      index: function(){
        checkSafe();
        return index;
      }
    };
  }
}
```